# Can't find the contents of a 'div' using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some information about MLB players from the MLB website. 
However, using urllib2 and BeautifulSoup, I can't find the contents under the 'div'. But I can clearly see the contents on Chrome.

An example is that, going to page (http://mlb.mlb.com/team/player.jsp?player_id=150378). The Status info on the upper right side shows 'Released'. But I can't find this string/content using BS4.

Here's my code:

```
base_url = 'http://mlb.mlb.com/team/player.jsp?player_id=150378'
request = urllib2.Request(base_url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
player_status = soup.findAll('div',id='player_status')
print player_status
```

I was expecting it to have a string like 'Status: Released',
but the result only shows

```
[<div id="player_status"></div>]
```

I have never encountered this problem before. Can someone help me with this?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Player information on the page is coming from the response of an additional XHR request to the JSON API. You can simulate it, for example, using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> url = "http://mlb.mlb.com/lookup/json/named.player_info.bam?sport_code=%27mlb%27&player_id=150378"
>>> 
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> data = response.json()
>>> data['player_info']['queryResults']['row']['status']
Released
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I also want to get his career stats? Also, why is your url different from mine? How do you get that url? Thanks!

Comment: @Jason the page data is dynamically constructed with a set of async calls to the different API endpoints - you can observe them in browser developer tools - network tab.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm not very familiar with the idea of API and how this website calls to different API to retrieve the info, and also how to use the network tab. Can you refer me to any links that can teach and get me started on this?